# const compile error on class method

Tags: c++, constants

I am receiving this error invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ from this code:

```
// in account.h
struct account {
    char* get_name ( ) const;
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE+1];
};
//in account.cxx
char* account::get_name ( ) const
{
    return name;
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type should be `const char*` as well:

```
const char* get_name ( ) const;
```

It is because in a const member function, `this` pointer becomes a const, as a result of which every member of the class becomes const, which means `name` which is declared as `char[N]`, becomes `const char[N]` in a const member function. `const char[N]` can converts into only `const char*`, hence you need to make the return type `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a non const pointer. You want to return a const char:

```
// in account.h
const char* get_name ( ) const;

//in account.cxx
const char* account::get_name ( ) const
{
    return name;
}
```

The reason is that your method is declared const, but the pointer you're returning could be used to modify name, which would be a violation of the method's const promise.

Answer (score 0):

Since get_name is a const method, all the members of the implicit object are const in the context of that method. By returning name as a char *, you are dropping the const qualifier from name. You could return const char *.